# Change the url with Angular UI-Router, do nothing else

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

There doesn't appear to be a built-in way to update the url without running all of the other processes, e.g. invoking controllers.

The option "reload", only works with `$location.search()`

Is there a method, or approach to achieve

How may I achieve something similar to:

```
$state.go('stateName', params, {justChangeTheUrl: true})
```

With Angular UI-Router?

Comment: just define your state url with this param `{url: 'stateName?reload}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to change the url without having that change processed by ui-router then you can use the following perfectly acceptable hack (coffeescript):

```
scopeOff = $scope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  scopeOff()

$location.path 'just/change/the/url'
```

**Notes**

Normally making a change to the browser url via `$location.path()` would trigger ui-router to begin its processing. This processing starts with the ui-router specific event called `$stateChangeStart`.

In the code above, however, you are catching and, via `e.preventDefault()`, throwing away this initial call to `$stateChangeStart` event and so preventing ui-router from processing the url change.

The watch on the `$stateChangeStart` event is 'single use', that is the code automatically detaches itself from the event after one run (this is what the call to `scopeOff()` is doing).

The net effect is to change the url in the browser without triggering ui-router processing and to only apply this restriction to the one url you have just changed. Neat, but not as neat as the new `deferIntercept` feature that will be with us soon.

Comment: Won't preventDefault prevent the url from changing too?

Comment: @TaylorMac Please see the `Notes` I have added to the answer.

Comment: Note on deferIntercept, this allows you to intercept the stateChange process, but it appears that you can only modify when the entire process (of the route updating and state changing) occurs. So to update the URL without changing the state, you would need to not just Defer the process, but cancel it completely, and update the url manually yourself, which is completely prevented by Angular's $route service.

Answer (score 0):

Define state parameter in url

```
 $stateProvider.state('stateName', {
     url: '/state/path?reload'
 });
```

But be carefull, every `$location.search()` change on `reload` param will trigger `$stateChangeStart` event, and your controller will be recreated

Comment: What about if we don't want the state to reload only sometimes, I think this is why having an option at the call site is better

Comment: yes it is, but there are no proper solution, just wierd hacks